# If I delete a clique from a perfect graph, is the resulting graph still perfect?

Tags: graph-theory

Some context: I'm trying to prove that all perfect graphs are normal, and I'm proceeding by a deletion of vertices.

My question is: If I delete a clique from a perfect graph, is the resulting graph still perfect? I tried doing an example and used the interval graph which is always perfect. It turns out that yes, this is true, but I can't intuitively understand why. Hence I'm not fully convinced on using this argument in my actual proof.

Can anyone confirm whether this is actually true and help me understand why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of perfect includes all induced subgraphs (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph)).  To paraphrase, a perfect graph is a graph in which the chromatic number of *every induced subgraph* equals the order of the largest clique of that subgraph.

Thus, if you remove any vertex, the graph is still perfect.  If you remove the vertices of the clique one by one, you still get a perfect graph.

Comment: Though if "delete a clique" means "delete the edges of the clique", leaving the vertices alone, then no guarantees can be made.

Comment: I mean deleting the vertices of a clique!

Comment: @happysoul09 then since, as the answer says, deleting vertices is essentially the same as taking an induced subgraph, the statement is trivially true. And further, it is true if you delete any set of vertices, not just cliques.